# computing posterior probability $P(t=0|x)$ from binary classification

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, bayesian

Considering that input $x$ is a scalar, the data generation process works as follows:

- First, a target t is sampled from {0, 1} with equal probability.
- If t = 0, x is sampled from a uniform distribution over the interval
  [0, 1].
- If t = 1, x is sampled from a uniform distribution over the
  interval [0, 2].

I'm trying to find the formula for $P(t=1)$, $P(t=0)$, $P(x|t=1)$ and $P(x|t=0)$ and then find the posterior probability $P(t = 0|x)$ as a function of $x$.

So far I have that $P(t=1)$ and $P(t=0)$ $=$ $\frac12$ but I wasn't sure how to find $P(x|t=1)$ and $P(x|t=0)$.

I know from there we can just use $P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$ to compute the probability $P(t = 0|x)$ as a function of $x$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have prior $T\sim Ber(1/2)$

You have data generation model, aka model of observation
\begin{equation}
f_{X|T=0}(x)=\begin{cases}
1,&0\leq x \leq 1\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_{X|T=1}(x)=\begin{cases}
1/2,&0\leq x \leq 2\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

All you need is to apply Bayes rule in the form

\begin{equation}
p_{T|X=x}(t)=\frac{f_{X|T=t}(x)p_T(t)}{f_X(x)}
\end{equation}
to obtain posterior.

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking.  The density function in both cases are constants over their intervals f(x|t=0)=1 [0,1] and f(x|t=1)= 0.5 [0,2].

Comment: then what would be the posterior probability $P(t=0|x)$ as a function of x?